# Global dimension of translation algebra

Tags: homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

What is the Hochschild cohomological dimension of the "translation algebra":  $\mathbb{C}\langle x,y\rangle/(xy-yx-x)$?

I expect it to be $2$, but I haven;t found a serious argument as to why this should be so...

Comment: I've deleted the tags "algebraic geometry" and "category theory" (please explain why they fit to the question).

Comment: algebraic geometry .. because I'm thinking of algebraic geometry as encompassing nc geometry and categories ..  so I could get your attention with this question (seriously); it worked (sorry about that though it is against the etiquette of this website on my part)

Comment: Hold on... I have the answer to this one... let me post it in a couple hours (I'm working on the details right now :) ).

Comment: @CSA Seems like quite a couple of hours by now ... :-)